# How to write AMD compatible JavaScript classes?

Tags: javascript, amd

What is the best method for writing AMD compatible JavaScript classes to be used as part of a modular app?

I usually write my classes using the singleton approach. Unless there is some trick to making it work with AMD, this does not appear to be compatible.

Comment: I just ran across UMD (https://github.com/umdjs/umd). It provides several examples (aggregated from the wild) of how to add AMD/CJS compatibility. The common theme seems to be to invoke a factory method (which can be chosen dynamically based on environment) and then pass in a "normal" IIFE.

Comment: Excellent list of examples! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we use AMD, and most of our files are singletons. We actually don't really declare a 'class' to only be used once (singleton) - we specifically define the one object instance, though to some people that's just a technical distinction. Here's an example:

```
// mylib.js
define(["otherlib"],

function(otherlib) {

return {
  doThing: function() {
    return otherlib.action("thing");
  }
};
});
```

In case you're wondering: Requiring this file 7 times will actually return the very same object each time - it won't get recreated.